# Want to call Webapi set entry Suite CRM 6.5

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm, sugarbean

I have a Login form with three fields. I want to post the data into a specific module of sugar through API. Where do I write that API? I set the entry point and the call but don't know how to hit that API.

Answer (score 0):

Custom API methods should be written in the following file:

```
custom/service/v4_1_custom/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php
```

This is described in the old but relevant [sugarcrm docs](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Integration/Web_Services/v1_-_v4.1/Extending_Web_Services/) and then should be available like any other suite API call.